# Setting a modal dialog with jQuery prevents a dropdown from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

Let us say I have the following HTML:

```
<select>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>a</option>
</select>​
```

And the following javascript:

```
$("<div>").dialog({
    modal: true
});
//... some other code
$(".ui-widget-overlay").remove(); //remove what makes the modal dialog `modal`
```

For some reason when I try to select from the dropdown it no longer works...

How do I fix this?

I am using Chrome 22.0.1229.94 (Official Build 161065) m

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/gATRg/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an overlay is created, some events are bound to the document that prevent clicking.  An overlay is a widget in an of itself, and the dialog stores a reference to it.  If you destroy the overlay in the 'correct' way, then you get the behavior you're looking for.

See this fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/Waxen/gATRg/6/

Code:

```
var div = $("<div>")

div.dialog({
    modal: true
});

div.data().dialog.overlay.destroy();
```